# How to show selected value of dropdown list from database in php

Tags: php

How do I show the selected value of a dropdown list from my mysql database. The dropdown list is dependent to my `Category` dropdown list. These are the codes:

```
<?php $id = $_GET["id"];
if(!$pupcon){
    die(mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($database_pupcon, $pupcon);

$getDropdown2 = mysql_query("select * from tblitemname where CategoryID = $id");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getDropdown2)){
        echo "<option value=\"".$row["ItemID"]."\">".$row["Item_Name"]."</option>";
    }   ?>
```

Here are the codes for the first dropdown list (`Category`) which populates the `Item Name` dropdown.

```
<select name="Category" id="Category" class="field select large" onChange="loadXMLDoc(this.value);">
                                <?php do {  ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['CategoryID']?>"<?php if (!(strcmp($row_Recordset1['CategoryID'], $row_editRecordset['CategoryID']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $row_Recordset1['CategoryName']?></option>
                                <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); $rows = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1); if($rows > 0) {
  mysql_data_seek($Recordset1, 0);
  $row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);}?>
                            </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

While you're listing out the drop down options, you can check to see if the current `ItemID` matches the passed `id` value.  If it matches, throw a `selected="selected"` in there.  Try:

```
$selected = ($row['ItemID'] == $id);
echo "<option value=\"".$row["ItemID"]."\" ".($selected ? " selected=\"selected\"":"").">".$row["Item_Name"]."</option>";
```

**EDIT**

I tried to clean up the code some...not sure why you're using a `do...while` because `$row_Recordset1` wouldn't be available on the first iteration.

```
<select name="Category" id="Category" class="field select large" onChange="loadXMLDoc(this.value);">
    <?php 
    while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)) {  
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['CategoryID']; ?>"<?php if (!(strcmp($row_Recordset1['CategoryID'], $row_editRecordset['CategoryID']))) { echo " selected=\"selected\""; } ?>>
    <?php echo $row_Recordset1['CategoryName']; ?>
    </option>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: The dropdown list does not display anything. I've edited my question and included the codes of the first dropdown list.

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary `echo` where? I copied his codes exactly the way it is and changed `$id` to `$row_Recordset1['ItemID']`. I'm trying to create an edit function and I use `Recordset1` to display the values stored into my database

Comment: sorry gabriel I just gave a glance over it did not notice that php tag.

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary So what do I do now?  Need help ASAP thank you

Comment: @GabrielAlain updated answer. What's the purpose of resetting the `$row_Recordset1` to the first result?

Comment: @AaronW. Same result. The codes for the `Category` dropdown list were generated by Dreamweaver and so is `$Recordset1`

Comment: @GabrielAlain Updated code since it had a couple missing semicolons. Not sure what the issue would be if that's not it. Enable your PHP error reporting to make sure there aren't any issues.

Comment: @AaronW. The same thing happened. The second dropdown value does not display the selected value though it is populated when I change the selected value on the `Category` dropdown list. I already enabled the PHP error reporting.

Comment: Make sure you aren't overwriting variables on the next drop down

Comment: i think you can try strcasecmp may be case sensitivity there. Try it

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code inside while

```
$selected=$row["ItemID"]==$id ?'Selected':'';
echo "<option value=\"".$row["ItemID"]."\" {$selected} >".$row["Item_Name"]."</option>";;
```